# Facebook sdk sample application FriendPickerSamplenot working

Tags: android, xml, facebook

I have downloaded facebook sdk by registering my application on facebook developers. I got some sample applications .When i tried to run FriendPickerSample application i got the message in console as "installation failed due to invalid apk file".After that i followed the instructions in developers website,but still the problem exist.Can anyone help me know what the problem is?

the code in android manifest file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.facebook.samples.friendpicker"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />s
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<application android:label="@string/app_name"
             android:icon="@drawable/icon"
             android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
             android:name=".FriendPickerApplication"
        >
    <activity android:name="FriendPickerSampleActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name"
              android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="PickFriendsActivity"
              android:label="Pick Friends">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity"
              android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
              android:label="@string/app_name" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/app_id"/>
</application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: There is an extra `s` near `android:targetSdkVersion` ?

Comment: oh..sorry Raptor ..it is jst my mistake when i tried to save that file using cntrl+s. But the problem is not that. And i tried now by removing that s also.